# How to align photo and text and display it properly?

Tags: html, css

i am currently unable to position my image and p tag properly and align them side by side here is my html/php code:

```
<?php
//If the user is logged in
$getposts = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to='$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getposts,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $body = $row['body'];   
                        $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                        $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                        $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];  
     echo "
     <article class='post'>
     <div class='post-content'>
<div class='content'>
<img src='https://d324imu86q1bqn.cloudfront.net/uploads/user/avatar/46407/ello-large-a74c9662.png' id='post_photo' alt=''></img>
<p>$body</p>
</div>
</div></article>
     ";
     }
?>
```

and i am using this css code:

```
.post-content {
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#read {
    font-size:0.85rem;
    line-height:1.5;
}
#post_photo{
    border-radius: 256px;
    width: 130px; height: 130px;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

But the image is not aligning itself with the p tag and display it properly in left side and right side p tag with some gap in between.

Comment: Learn how to use `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image and the text `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`. Do `display: table` to content and also, remove `float: left;` from the image styles.

Also, you were not closing the `img` tag correctly.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
.post-content {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#read {
  font-size:0.85rem;
  line-height:1.5;
}

#post_photo{
  border-radius: 256px;
  width: 130px; height: 130px;
  /*float: left;*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

/***** NEW STYLES BELOW *****/

.content{
  display: table;
}

#post_photo, .content > p{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content > p{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article class='post'>
  <div class='post-content'>
    <div class='content'>
      <img src='https://d324imu86q1bqn.cloudfront.net/uploads/user/avatar/46407/ello-large-a74c9662.png' id='post_photo' alt='' /> <!-- img tags are self closing tags -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris hendrerit mauris ac pellentesque ultricies. Quisque gravida bibendum justo non sodales. In tortor sapien, elementum quis tincidunt ac, pellentesque nec nunc. Fusce lacinia mollis mauris, sit amet mattis nibh ultrices id. Curabitur eleifend metus massa, vitae accumsan tellus commodo ut. Proin odio nunc, volutpat nec bibendum quis, scelerisque a diam. Curabitur lacinia vestibulum blandit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: but this does not work if text in p is more than 1 line.